# If Specific Value Exists in Row, Change All Remaining Values in Row to New Value

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyr

So here is what the data looks like:

```
x1       x2   x3   x4   x5       x6          x7         x8        x9
0        0    0    1    2        Complete    Closed     Closed    Closed
0        0    0    0    0        0           0          0         Complete
0        1    2    3    Complete 1           1          1         1
```

I want to find a way to replace all remaining values in a row to "Closed" after the cell where the value "Complete" occurs. It should always just say Closed after the value Complete occurs so as you can see, there are a few rows that are not following this logic which is an error I need to correct.

The final data should look like this:

```
x1       x2   x3   x4   x5       x6          x7         x8        x9
0        0    0    1    2        Complete    Closed     Closed    Closed
0        0    0    0    0        0           0          0         Complete
0        1    2    3    Complete Closed      Closed     Closed    Closed
```

I was thinking a for loop could just run every row in the data and check for the existence of the value "Complete" and then just change the remaining values in that row to "Closed" but I'm not sure what the syntax would look like.

Comment: What class are the columns, `character` or `factor`?

Comment: The Column class is character for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write a simple utility function for clarity:

```
close_after_complete = function(x) {
  ifelse(cumsum(x == "Complete") >= 1 & x != "Complete", "Closed", x)
}
```

You can read `cumsum(x == "Complete") >= 1` as '*we've seen at least 1 "complete"*', and, of course, `x != "Complete"` is '*but the current value is not "Complete"*'. When both those conditions are met, you want to change the value to "closed".

Since we're operating on rows, converting to a matrix (implicitly) and using `apply` makes sense:

```
t(apply(df, 1, close_after_complete))
#      x1  x2  x3  x4  x5         x6         x7       x8       x9        
# [1,] "0" "0" "0" "1" "2"        "Complete" "Closed" "Closed" "Closed"  
# [2,] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"        "0"        "0"      "0"      "Complete"
# [3,] "0" "1" "2" "3" "Complete" "Closed"   "Closed" "Closed" "Closed"
```

You can convert back to data frame with `as.data.frame()` if you want.

```
# using this data
df = read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, text = "x1       x2   x3   x4   x5       x6          x7         x8        x9
0        0    0    1    2        Complete    Closed     Closed    Closed
0        0    0    0    0        0           0          0         Complete
0        1    2    3    Complete 1           1          1         1")
```